# Understanding the "-p" option to "command" in Bash and its interaction with the default PATH

Tags: bash, command, path

The `command` command in `bash`: Run command with arguments ignoring any shell function named command.

The `-p` option means to use a default value of `$PATH` that is guaranteed to find all of the standard utilities.

What exactly is the default `PATH` mentioned here? When I define `export PATH="/home/ozgur/":$PATH`, don't I add a new `PATH` path over the default value?

For example:

```bash
$ export PATH="/home/ozgur/":$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/home/ozgur/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
$ script.sh
hey, i am working !
$ command -p script.sh
hey, i am working !
```

When I used the `-p` option with the `command` command, I would expect it to ignore the new `PATH` path I had defined, but that didn't happen. What exactly am I missing here? What is the point of using the `-p` option if changes to the user's `PATH` path are not overridden?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with bash v4.3.48.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> What exactly am I missing here?

The `script.sh` command is hashed. If you run `hash -r`, then `command -p script.sh` will fail as expected. But if you run it directly, it will be hashed again.

This really looks like a bug in bash -- it does not happen in other shells.

Answer (score 0):

It sets up a basic PATH that bash calls `STANDARD_UTILS_PATH` - as of [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/838552/309584), the compile time default was:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/etc:/usr/etc
```

You can also see the source on [GNU Savannah](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;t=bash-5.2;a=blob;f=config-top.h#l75).

Comment: Note that the user indicates that the `script.sh` command is not found in the standard path but is still executed with `command -p script.sh`.  Their question is _why_ it is executed, as it should not be found.